# Binary path in the pgAdmin preferences

Tags: postgresql, restore, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I installed PostgreSQL because I need to restore a large `.backup` file I received for upload to another platform (it's 38 million rows which was apparently too large for the person to export any other way). When I try to "restore" in pgAdmin 4 I get the message:

> Please configure the PostgreSQL Binary Path in the Preferences dialog.

Is this just the path to the PostgreSQL folder? I can't find documentation on this on the PostgreSQL site. All I can find is:

> Use the fields in the Binary paths node to specify paths to the PostgreSQL binary utilities and EnterpriseDB Postgres Advanced Server binary utilities.

Is there an easier way to restore the database other than through pgAdmin?

Answer (score 54):

Configure pgAdmin->Paths->Binary paths and set "PostgreSQL Binary Path" as shown in the screenshot.  Depending on your OS and installation details, the binaries may be located elsewhere.  Try

```
`which psql`
```

from the command line on linux/Unix systems.

A Windows example:
**PostgreSQL Binary Path:** `"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin"`
[image]

Comment: Be sure to click the Default radio button

Answer (score 35):

1. Select "Servers" item.
2. Select "Configure PgAdmin"

   [image: Select Servers item]
3. Enter to local path Postgresql "bin" folder.

   [image: Enter the path to "pg bin" folder]

---

- On OSX [the path is](https://postgresapp.com/documentation/install.html) `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin`
- On Mac OSX Sierra the path was `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin` - I believe this is the default location from the EnterpriseDB installer for 9.6 that automatically installs PgAdmin 4.
- On Linux the path is `/usr/bin`

  [image]

Answer (score 2):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

Just use [`pg_restore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html). That's all PgAdmin is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: I tried but it says pg command not found