# pgAdmin 4 v1.6 setting PostgreSQL Binary Path to a remote server to clear-up "The system cannot find the path specified." error

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

Just wondering how to go about assigning binary path to a remote server. I have pgAdmin on my personal computer, but the server (CentOS) that PostgreSQL resides on is at a different location.

Comment: What do you mean by "assigning binary path to a remote server". Do you want to connect to postgresql instance running on remote server via pgadmin, or something else

Comment: Hi, this answer has a picture showing the option I am referring to. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149169/binary-path-in-the-pgadmin-preferences. I can access the server remotely and run standard CRUD requests. However, if I try to do something like import a CSV, or `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` I get the error in the title. The error is related to this option in pgAdmin. The option is looking for the install location for PostgreSQL. All the examples I have seen use a local example, so curious if you can specify a remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because when using `EXPLAIN` or `pg_dump` from pgAdmin, the program uses the utilities in its install directory `$DIR/../runtime` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v1\runtime` to execute these commands. You can put this location in the Postgresql binary path and continue with the operation.